# How to press multiple buttons at the same time?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am developing an android application that consists of a 2 dimensional array of buttons. when i touch the buttons, at a time only one button is pressed. i want to press multiple buttons at the same time. please give me a sample code.

Comment: call progamatically button.performClick()

Answer (score 0):

You can click a button programmatically by using the button.performClick() method inside your other onclicklistener button

Answer (score 0):

To press another button(`button2`), just call `button2.performClick()` from `button1` listeners `onClick()` method.

**Here is an example:**

```
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button 1 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            button2.performClick();
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button 2 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Do something
        }
    });
```

Comment: i have created a 2 dimensional array of buttons. their ids are not set. by using one finger how can i touch multiple buttons in sequence